# Problema de acentuação no mysql e php

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, mysqli, tabela-banco-de-dados

Estou com um problema na acentuação no meu banco de dados. Já pesquisei bastante sobre isso, fiz muitos testes e nada.

Eis o que acontece:

Minha database já está **"utf8_unicode_ci"** fiz um simples teste para registrar um nome como "Gê" as tabelas estão aceitando normalmente.

O problema é quando eu faço isso do meu arquivo de cadastro de usuário. O resultado na tabela é o seguinte: "Gê"

O meu php de conexão com o banco de dados está assim:

```
public function openConnection() { 
    $this->conn = new mysqli($this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass, $this->dbname);
    $this->conn->set_charset("utf8");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        throw new Exception("Could not establish connection with database");
    }
}
```

PS: já tentei o formato **latin1_swedish_ci** também e nada

Comment: Gê, você precisa avaliar também a codificação de seu arquivo e codificação que o arquivo está sendo instruído, ou por html ou php.

Comment: Não tem como seu Database "estar utf8_unicode_ci", isso é collation. Não pode confundir collation com charset (o ideal é os dois serem compatíveis, mas não são a mesma coisa). Além disso, tem que testar se a aplicação está mandando dados em UTF-8 (e isso não tem nada a ver com o código postado).